# plugins or addons that add more nodes?

Tags: materials, procedural

Are there any plug-ins or addons that add more nodes for use with Blender materials?

nodes like warp, wood, vector drawing, etc ???

thanks

Comment: https://blendermarket.com/categories/materials-shaders-textures

Comment: Thank you for your help

but I don't want materials

I want nodes to build materials, example
warp, wood, vector drawing, etc ???

exist ?

thanks

Comment: in this link video at 14:54 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUpzBP0rMM0&t=816s

the guy uses node: Space warp 2

Where can I find this node and others with different functions? even if it's paid?

thanks

Comment: That's a node group. It simply contains an assortment of the usual nodes. People who create complex materials, can group parts of them. You would find such groups in Duartes linked blender market page.

Comment: I get the general impression that blender addons must be python-scripts only, whereas material/shading nodes must be programming in c, and I don't see any way to load extra c code into blender as an extension/plugin/addon; (sure its technically possible to have python load a c library and proxy it into blender, but the blender api won't allow python to register that as a new node type)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking up Open Shading Language (OSL). There are a number of repos using it available on Github.

To use it, you'll need to be using Cycles (Eevee, in the interest of being fast, does not support OSL at this time). Additionally, you'll need to be rendering on your CPU, not your GPU; while it's possible in theory, no one has implemented OSL rendering on the GPU yet and it's no small undertaking.

After you have that set up on your Render context, you'll want to select the checkbox for "Open Shading Language". This prepares Blender to run its internal OSL interpreter.

After that, in your shader, you'll have a Script node available. Add one. It seems simple at first; you just have a box for the OSL file and a toggle for a file-internal vs. file-external location; assuming you've got an OSL, click external, and open it up in the box. Once your OSL is open, the script node will have a lot more character, along with (presumably) some new inputs and outputs. Hook them up, play with your new node!

I hope that helps.